# slim displays JSON response from its file, calling file never seems to get response

Tags: php, slim

working on my first slim project, so i suspect there's something simple i'm missing.

this is in a WAMP dev environment.

i have a file called getValue.php that has a simple form and passes a value to a slim API file called index.php.

all the processing on the index.php side is working except slim seems to simply display the json response in http://localhost/project/index.php/value, rather than pass it back to getValue.php.  i want getValue.php to handle the response display.

here's getValue.php

```
<?php
if (!empty($_POST['uid'])) {
    $json = 'index.php/value?uid=' . $_POST['uid'];
    $arr = file_get_contents($json);
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
        <title>value</title>
    </head>

    <body>
    <form action="index.php/value" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="uid"/>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
    <br/>

    <?php
        if(!empty($arr)){
            echo json_decode($arr, true);
        }
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

here's index.php

```
<?php

use \Slim\Slim;

$app = new Slim(array(
    'mode' => 'development'
));

$app->post('/value', function () use ($app){
    $uid = $app->request->params('uid');
    $uid = $uid + 1;
    $arr = array("uid" => $uid);

    $response = $app->response();
    $response['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
    $response->body(json_encode($arr));
});
```

postman seems to send, receive and display the response just fine.

any ideas?

Comment: What is expected GET URL?

Comment: @Tpojka...i'd hope it'd be something like getValue.php?uid=12345

Comment: What is your requirement? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @davide...i'm trying to build an API that can be used by customers to manipulate data in our cloud based database.

so, in theory, getValue.php would be a page belonging to our customer.  they'd send some data to our API, the API would do some database logic, then reply with a numeric return.

Comment: @davide...i've been able to get public APIs made available by google and instagram to successfully respond and display in php almost identical to getValue.php.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you imagined, it's something simple: the action in your form is wrong. Since you want that `getValue.php` script handle the POST, you should use it as the form action. This way:

```
<form action="getValue.php" method="post">
```

The way you're doing now, you POST the form directly to the Slim route, bypassing the `getValue.php` script.

Comment: thanks.  this worked.  also needed to add the full path to the slim file url "http://localhost/project/index.php/value?uid="

Comment: Hey, @alexsd. Since that worked, it's a good idea accepting the answer to help others facing a similar issue to find a solution.